# Rebuses with an unknown symbol

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, language, geography

Each picture features the same unknown symbol. What does it mean? Where would you place it fit in the final answer?

> [image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The unknown symbol means ...

> ... **MONT**.

In the final answer, it is ...

> ... both at the front and at the back.

In the rebus, the mystery word ...

> ... is always at the front. The answers are place names:
>
>  MONT**PARNASSE** — PAR(m→N)A + (e)SSE(n)
>  MONT**ENEGRO** — GENE< (Hackman) + hiragana kana [RO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ro_(kana)) (thanks, Bass)
>  MONT**BLANC** — BLANC = white in French
>
>  MONTI**CELLO** — I (= X V/L) + CELLO
>  MONT**SERRAT** — RR (blank Rolls Royce logo) in SEAT
>  MONT**ERREY** — (su→E)RREY
>
>  MONT**EVIDEO** — Braille E + the [one who killed the radio star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Killed_the_Radio_Star)
>  MONT**REAL** — REAL, the Brazilian coin
>  MONT**GOMERY** — GO + REM< + Y (= [y], IPA symbol for German umlaut ü)

The final answer ...

> ... can be found by taking the indicated letters from the individual solutions after the MONT part. This yields "pel ier ver", and by surrounding that with two MONTs, we get:
>
>  [**Montpelier, Vermont**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montpelier,_Vermont)

Comment: Brilliant job, creator and solver both! (The "ro" is surely [hiragana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ro_(kana)), by the way).

Comment: Thanks. I'll second your accolades for the puzzle creator, @Bass. Thanks for the pointer on the wrong glyph.

Comment: Whoaaaaa. This is brilliant :D

Comment: Woah. I usually dislike rebuses, but that was so well done I think I'm into rebuses again. Well done to jafe & M Oehm!

Answer (score 2):

Partial

row 1 column 1

> parma: m-->n : **PARMA** + ?

row 2 column 3

> surrey - su + e = **ERREY**